# Need an event that will fire after activating a child form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am working with an existing WinForm application and it uses the following code to re-activate a child form that has previously been loaded:

```
private void Activate(Form frm)
{
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.ActivateMdiChild(frm);
}
```

The trouble I'm having is that when the form is re-activated, I can not seem to find *any* event on the form that gets raised naturally by the code above. I'm also having difficulty adding code to manually raise the event on the child form, and I think it's because I'm working with a generic `Form` object.

I've tried `Load`, `MdiChildActivate`, `MaximumSizeChanged`, `Activated` and a few other events, and none of them fire upon running the code above. I basically need to update some of the form elements after that code is called above and figured an event would work well.

Does anyone know an event that will be raised *on the child form* after it has been reactivated?

Comment: why not create a function in the child form that you can call if you want to activate it?

Comment: @GianAcuna - As shown from the code example, `frm` is a generic instance of a `Form`. Therefore custom methods would not be exposed via that base type. I would have to cast it to the right type of form to see the custom methods, but that logic is not in place to know which form is being activated. That's why I wanted to use an event that was available to all forms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Enter event of the child form?  I don't think it fires if the form is already active though.

Another option would be to cast it as your own type and add your own event, then fire it directly.